# HairNet Add-on is screwy

Tags: add-on, hair

[image]Hi I'm still trying to work on a braid, but it keeps acting all screwy.

The first image is the result and the second is what it looked like before. Then when I figure out that error it says that the mesh guides are not the same length.

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1QqSpjGz4KgfaY2YlozwF1AScxMrXXtI-

[image]

Tutorial Link: [Creating Braid in Blender](https://youtu.be/5pxZtmlqtvc)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your braid curves all have the same number of points. Go into edit mode, and in the viewport under display overlays, turn on statistics. It should show you how many point you have per curve. Delete a bunch so that your point count per curve matches and you should be good to go.

Comment: Is that the the same amount of vertices of the mesh to match to curve or both curves to match one another or the same amount of vertices on the curve to the mesh?

Comment: The curves that your are using to generate your hair from the hairnet should all have the same number of points. I am guessing you have three curves per braid, so all three should have the same count. (eg. 20-20-20pts per curve).

Comment: The tutorial that I'm following shows that I have to click on the hair emitter and when I do it doesn't work. I just added same amount to points to my curves and when I do the emitter... nothing.